# Query about arrayadapter

Tags: android

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayadapter=new 

ArrayAdapter<string>(Sipnner_apActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,arrarylist);
```

Here what is the meaning of `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` and why does the `Arrayadapter` class belong to `widget` class & why not belong to "util" class.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

R stands for "Resources". Android has built in resources in the android.R.* namespace and your application has resources in the your_app_namespace.R.* namespace.

There are a bunch of reasons why you should use resources, but one of them is to support multiple languages and screen sizes.

For example, for an activity, you might have a layout called "helloworld.xml". Eclipse will generate a constant value for your_app_namespace.R.layout.helloworld.

This helloworld.xml layout file will be in your res/layout folder. However, if you wanted helloworld.xml to look different if the application was installed on a tablet, you could put another copy of helloworld.xml in a folder called layout-large. It will automatically choose which helloworld.xml to use.

To answer your question, **android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item** is a layout that android has by default. It's used so you don't have to create your own layout for spinner items if all you need is something simple.

ArrayAdapter is not part of the util namespace because it's mostly used for widgets.

Answer (score 0):

This is what android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item look like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
/* //device/apps/common/assets/res/any/layout/simple_spinner_item.xml
**
** Copyright 2006, The Android Open Source Project
**
** Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); 
** you may not use this file except in compliance with the License. 
** You may obtain a copy of the License at 
**
**     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 
**
** Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software 
** distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, 
** WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. 
** See the License for the specific language governing permissions and 
** limitations under the License.
*/
-->
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

It's basically a template exactly a TextView widget that your arraylist elements would be bind to it.

Also in general Adapters is an interface in the android ui toolkit between a source of data and UI components,adapters are used to feed the data to the ui toolkit.